# Random Number Generator from 0 to 20 and User inputs a number that can be true or false

Tags: python, random, input

So basically I made a Python code that gives a random number between 0 and 20. When I run it, it makes the guessed number false while the guessed number is true. I tried to make only one answer true by telling it is 14, which must be true. But I made a mistake. It is the second time i used input so please do not tell me stupid please.
Thanks for helping <3

```
from random import *

def main():
    question = input("Guess a number between 0 and 20 \n")
    randomInt = randrange(14, 15)

    if randomInt == question:
        print("You are right! It is " + str(randomInt))
    else:
        print("Wrong the number is " + str(randomInt))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: ^ Hint `question` isn't an integer.

Comment: The OP seems to realize that `randomInt` is not a string, due to the call to `str(randomInt)`, but not aware that, for example, `"14" == 14` is false due to the type difference.

Comment: There are languages that will implicitly convert strings to integers. Python is not one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your input in an int() so like this:

```
from random import *

def main():
    question = int(input("Guess a number between 0 and 20 \n"))
    randomInt = randrange(14, 15)

    if randomInt == question:
        print("You are right! It is " + str(randomInt))
    else:
        print("Wrong the number is " + str(randomInt))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

also consider changing your import to just "import random" and defining your random number as "randomInt = random.randint(14,14). Using random will give you exactly the range you want so random.randint(0,10) is exactly 0 to 10 to instead of 0 to 9 with just randrange

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to convert your Input to int before you compare the two because your input is being interpreted as a string but your random gen is an int.

"14" is not the same as 14 therefore the check fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while ago! It asks for an input, but with input, it is made to expect text, so any input into input is treated as text. Instead, you need to use the following code:

```
question = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 20 \n"))
```

This will tell Python that you are dealing with a number. :]

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help you!!!!!!!!!!

```
import random
def main():
guess=input("Guess a number between 0 and 20  \n")
  randomint=random.randint(0,20)
  #print(randomint)

  if  randomint==guess:
        print("Wow, Superb", randomint)
  else:
        print("Whooo!!!!!!",randomint)

if  __name__=='__main__':
  main()
```